# Windows utility for testing the correctness of command-line arguments?

Tags: windows, console

Many years ago, I remember downloading a Windows utility that you could use to test the correctness of calling an executable with arguments from a PS/cmd script.

For instance, let's say that you were calling msdeploy.exe from a build script and you wanted to check that the arguments being passed in the call were correct.  You would call the utility executable instead of msdeploy.exe with the same arguments, and it would output details of all the arguments to the console.  You could then check whether the arguments were well-formed.

I can't remember the name of the utility.  It was free, and maybe developed by an MS employee.  Does anyone know what it is called, and whether it is still available for download?

Comment: A program cannot evaluate whether any given command line is valid for any given tool. There is nothing in an executable file that would provide this information.

Comment: Probably it was particular case of code requirement check for safety. Was it something like `PEVerify` tool?

Comment: @Daemon-5 No, the program didn't verify anything. It just output to the console the arguments it had been provided with. That's all it did. The reason why this was useful is because, if you have a PS script that dynamically generates some arguments to pass to an executable, you want to test that the parameters being passed to that executable are well-formed (arguments passed in the correct order, each argument being constructed as per requirements).